# What's the use of C# keyword fixed/unsafe?

Tags: c#

What's the use of C# keyword fixed/unsafe?

For example, *[C# fixed Keyword (unsafe)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fixed)*

```
using System;

class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        fixed (char* value = "sam")
        {
            char* ptr = value;
            while (*ptr != '\0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(*ptr);
                ++ptr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I need to fix it in the first place?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153376/fixed-statement-in-c-sharp  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85479/c-sharp-unsafe-fixed-code  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173002/unsafe-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: You need to fix it so that the pointer you're using will stay valid. But the uses of unsafe code are relatively few and far between, to be honest. I've been writing C# for many years and still don't even remember the various rules for unsafe coding.

Comment: check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım I do not think that is a duplicate - that question asks when this asks why as well.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48782992/7713750

Comment: No answer explains this statement found in the linked example: "*There is a small cost to using the fixed statement. So **it will only help** on operations that spend significant amounts of time in unsafe code*" which is at least ambiguous, maybe wrong, depending on how you read the first part. What is unclear is whether "non fixed" pointers are adjusted by the CLR when GC relocates the allocated memory block (at the cost of some time loss), or are not and start pointing to a wrong place (hence the 'fixed' keyword is not *optional* but mandatory with pointers -- this is my understanding).

Answer (score 55):

C# is a *managed language* that means the memory is managed automatically, i.e. not by you. If you did not use `fixed` by the time you come to modify the memory pointed to by your pointer C# could have moved the variable to another memory location so you could be modifying something else!

`fixed` is logically fixing the variable in memory so it does not move around.

Why does C# move variables in memory around? To compact the memory otherwise programs would use up more memory available to them if objects that are no longer alive left holes other objects cannot fit in (heap memory fragmentation).

I used `fixed` extensively [in a .NET library](https://github.com/markmnl/FalconUDP/blob/single-threaded/src/Packet.cs#L556) designed for resource constrained devices to avoid creating garbage copying into buffers and find this feature sorely lacking in other managed languages where you cannot do the same. When writing games in a managed language garbage collection is often one of the biggest bottlenecks so having the ability not to create it is very helpful!

See my question here: [C# Copy variables into buffer without creating garbage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307431/c-sharp-copy-variables-into-buffer-without-creating-garbage) for one reason why.

Comment: "I used fixed extensively in a .NET library designed for resource constrained devices to avoid creating garbage copying into buffers and find this feature sorely lacking in other managed languages where you cannot do the same. When writing games in a managed language garbage collection is often one of the biggest bottlenecks so having the ability not to create it is very helpful!" --> Thank you, but sorry can you elaborate. I seems to get the idea, really pinning memory location is for Performance. But I don't really... see how, would appreciate if you elaborate on this!

Comment: Pinning memory doesn't give the performance the ability to use pointers to modify memory, in my case copy several variables into a buffer without creating garbage can give performance where garbage collection time is an issue, see my linked question.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Read it. How much performance gain you had I wonder by not using intermediate byte[] and copy via pined memory location instead? Was it significant?

Comment: If you are on Phone or device like Ouya (running mono) and copying a lot it was noticeable - the app freezes when the GC has to run - now it doesn't because there is no garbage.

Comment: Great appreciate your input.

Answer (score 14):

`unsafe` is necessary to deal in pointers.

`fixed` has two uses:

- it allows you to pin an array and obtain a pointer to the data
- when used in an `unsafe struct` field, it declares a "fixed buffer" - a reserved block of space in a type that is accessed via pointers rather than regular fields

To answer with a specific example - here's some code that is used to perform semantic equality between two `byte[]` of arbitrary size...

```
    internal static unsafe  int GetHashCode(byte[] value)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            if (value == null) return -1;
            int len = value.Length;
            if (len == 0) return 0;
            int octects = len / 8, spare = len % 8;
            int acc = 728271210;
            fixed (byte* ptr8 = value)
            {
                long* ptr64 = (long*)ptr8;
                for (int i = 0; i < octects; i++)
                {
                    long val = ptr64[i];
                    int valHash = (((int)val) ^ ((int)(val >> 32)));
                    acc = (((acc << 5) + acc) ^ valHash);
                }
                int offset = len - spare;
                while(spare-- != 0)
                {
                    acc = (((acc << 5) + acc) ^ ptr8[offset++]);
                }
            }
            return acc;
        }            
    }
```

So if, for example, the buffer was 1000 items, by treating it as a set of `long` we now only do 125 iterations rather than having to look individually at all 1000 - plus we completely bypass any array bounds checking (which the JIT may or may not remove, depending on how *obvious* it looks that you can't possibly be violating them).

Comment: Thanks Marc - "for example, the buffer was 1000 items, by treating it as a set of long we now only do 125 iterations rather than having to look individually at all 1000" --- not sure if I follow you but I am guessing you're saying it's basically "Performance Consideration". If you have a big object graph - sometimes, it's faster if you pin/fix its memory location while iterating over it? If so it's the only "Practical" usage I hear thus far (Everyone else just reiterate "yes fix it in memory")

Comment: @Swab.Jat if you look at the code, you can see that it is processing each item as a `long` rather than as a `byte` - so it is hashing 8 bytes each iteration. Yes, `unsafe` is usually used as a performance consideration. There is also the scenario where you obtain a pointer to completely unmanaged memory - interop scenarios, basically - but those are much rarer than performance uses.

Comment: hi Marc, thanks. Mark gave me a very useful example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307431/c-sharp-copy-variables-into-buffer-without-creating-garbage

Answer (score 4):

`Unsafe` code blocks are quite rare to be used. They are predominantly used if you want to create and make use of pointers. Also, any code in unsafe block is out of control of CLR. It is considered to be unverifiable (from MSDN) as far as CLR in concerned.

Now, when garbage collection happens, some object may well be relocated. When prefixed with fixed, we are telling the framework to not to relocate objects whose address pointers are pointing to.

Comment: Note that "Fixed" ia an interop issue. WHen you ge a pointer and hand it over to unmanaged code (for example to a native dll to dump some data there) you CAN NOT have the garbage collector move that object while your call is in progress. Hence fixing it on a location.

Comment: That's what MSDN says - fix memory location yes I get it. But why? Any practical usage why we need this language feature at all? Thanks

Comment: Mostly while doing interop and marshalling. When you want to retain pointers for longer durations.